# Is it permissible to use live bait for fishing

Tags: halacha

For example, would one run into the problem of tsar bale haim when impaling a live worm with a hook for the possibility of catching a kosher fish to eat?

Comment: the title seems relevant but I can't find the content https://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=25711&alias=halacha-hunting-vs-fishing